# How to arrange the Commands into specific order in j2me midp 2.0?

Tags: java-me

I have 6 commands in my Form. For example, submit,edit,save,cancel,back,logout. I want to keep the same order which I mentioned above. How I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the priority and the type, Generally, lowest priority values will appear first. Depending on the platform, certain types of Commands will go first or last (`Item` commands, for example, usually are placed before `Screen` Commands).

And well, probably you know this, but to set the priority you use the last parameter of any of the two constructors.

I assume you are using LCDUI.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To arrange the commands in a specific order you can use the method `arrangeCommand()` as follows:

```
public void arrangeCommand(Command c1,Command c2, Command c3,Command c4,Command c5,Command c6)
    {

    }
```